# First time making a REST service, calling from android

Tags: java, c#, android, asp.net, rest

I've recently started learning android programming and how to create a restful web service. I made a simple yahtzee game for android and to expand my knowledge on both platforms I wanted to implement a two player system using a restful service.

I made the service in asp.net MVC with the code as below which a get request to url/games/2 would return:

```
<Game>
   <Id>2</Id>
   <p1>100</p1>
    <p2>99</p2>
    <turn>1</turn>
</Game>
```

All I want to do is be able to create a new game by calling Post and then use Get to check if is your turn yet and then when you finish your turn using Put to update the game, changing your score and the turn so the other players get request will let their client know it is their turn. I know this is very basic for 2 player functionality but it's just what I'm trying to do learn this process. I have a game object in android but I'm not sure how to proceed. The direction I'm working on at the moment is HttpClient with post looking something like:

```
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("url/games")
```

But I don't see how to pass a parameter. My Post method in my service takes a game object as a parameter. If anyone could give me any advice I would greatly appreciate it.

Model, Game.cs:

```
namespace YahtzTest.Models
{
    public class Game
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int turn { get; set; }
        public int p1 { get; set; }
        public int p2 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Controller, GamesController.cs:

```
    namespace YahtzTest.Controllers
{
    public class GamesController : ApiController
    {
        static readonly IGameRepository repository = new GameRepository();

        public IEnumerable<Game> GetAllGames()
        {
            return repository.GetAll();
        }

        public Game GetGame(int id)
        {
            Game item = repository.Get(id);
            if (item == null)
            {
                throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
            }
            return item;
        }

        public HttpResponseMessage PostGame(Game item)
        {
            item = repository.Add(item);
            var response = Request.CreateResponse<Game>(HttpStatusCode.Created, item);

            string uri = Url.Link("DefaultApi", new { id = item.Id });
            response.Headers.Location = new Uri(uri);
            return response;
        }

        public void PutGame(int id, Game game)
        {
            game.Id = id;
            if (!repository.Update(game))
            {
                throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
            }
        }

        public void DeleteGame(int id)
        {
            Game item = repository.Get(id);
            if (item == null)
            {
                throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
            }

            repository.Remove(id);
        }

    }
}
```

And a couple other files that the tutorial I followed included for storing my games, GameRepository.cs and IGameRepository.cs:

```
    namespace YahtzTest.Models
{
    interface IGameRepository
    {
        IEnumerable<Game> GetAll();
        Game Get(int id);
        Game Add(Game item);
        void Remove(int id);
        bool Update(Game item);
    }
}


    namespace YahtzTest.Models
{
    public class GameRepository : IGameRepository
    {
        private List<Game> games = new List<Game>();
        private int _nextId = 1;

        public GameRepository()
        {
            Add(new Game { turn = 0, p1 = 0, p2 = 0 });
            Add(new Game { turn = 1, p1 = 100, p2 = 99 });
            Add(new Game { turn = 0, p1 = 45, p2 = 75 });
        }



        public IEnumerable<Game> GetAll()
        {
            return games;
        }

        public Game Get(int id)
        {
            return games.Find(p => p.Id == id);
        }

        public Game Add(Game item)
        {
            if (item == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("item");
            }
            item.Id = _nextId++;
            games.Add(item);
            return item;
        }

        public void Remove(int id)
        {
            games.RemoveAll(p => p.Id == id);
        }

        public bool Update(Game item)
        {
            if (item == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("item");
            }
            int index = games.FindIndex(p => p.Id == item.Id);
            if (index == -1)
            {
                return false;
            }
            games.RemoveAt(index);
            games.Add(item);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically you write a string on POST. And on your server side, when onPostReceived you need to recreate your object from string. I don't know how you want to send your data (Content-Type), look one the

If you want to POST an object to your server then you can do it like this: (JSON Example)

```
        HttpClient httpClient = HttpHelper.getHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("yourServerAddress");
        httppost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
        httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");

        // StringEntity
        String inStr = yourObject.toString();
        StringEntity se = new StringEntity(inStr, HTTP.UTF_8);

        // Params
        HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
        params.setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.HTTP_ELEMENT_CHARSET, HTTP.UTF_8);
        httppost.setParams(params);         
        httppost.setEntity(se);

        // Fire and read response
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        // read answer
        String content = null;
        InputStream stream = null;
        try {
            if (response != null) {
                stream = response.getEntity().getContent();
                InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(stream, HTTP.UTF_8);
                BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(reader);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String cur;
                while ((cur = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(cur);
                }
                //here's your whole response from your server if you provide any
                content = sb.toString();
            }
        } finally {
            if (stream != null) {
                stream.close();
            }
        }           

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```